# Laravel Remember Me, running with Auth::attempt?

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this code:

```
public function postLogin() {
    // validate the info, create rules for the inputs
    $rules = array(
        'username'    => 'required', // make sure the email is an actual email
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3' // password can only be alphanumeric and has to be greater than 3 characters
    );

    // run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::route('login')
            ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
            ->withInput(Input::except('password')); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
    } else {

        $remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;
        // create our user data for the authentication
        $userdata = (array(
            'username'  => Input::get('username'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')
        ), $remember);

        // attempt to do the login
        if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {

            // validation successful!
            // redirect them to the secure section or whatever
            // return Redirect::to('secure');
            // for now we'll just echo success (even though echoing in a controller is bad)
            echo 'SUCCESS!';

        } else {

            // validation not successful, send back to form
            return Redirect::route('login')
             ->with('global', 'Incorrect username or password. Please try again.');
        }
    }
}
```

When it runs I get: `syntax error, unexpected ','`. Basically it isn't expecting the $remember to be passed there. Where is it meant to be? I've tried putting it here: `Auth::attempt($userdate), $remember) { }` but that didn't work either. It had the same error. Not sure what's going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Auth::viaRemember()` in your Authcontroller, to check if a user was already logged:

```
if (Auth::check() || Auth::viaRemember()) {...
```

And change your login-check as follows:

```
//Assuming, the remember-input is a checkbox and its value is 'on'
if (Auth::attempt($userData, (Input::get('remember') == 'on') ? true : false)) {...
```